# <thead> is not responsive in WordPress table on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

We have this website:
https://maquinasdesoldar.top/

And around half way down the page you see this table:
[image]

But it's spilling off the screen when the site is mobile size.

Weirdly, if I use the console editor and delete the thead element, the remainder of the table fits fine.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table-layout: fixed` property on table rule.